# Locust headless csv reports

Tags: python, locust

I am running Locust with the `--headless` parameter, as well as `--csv=locust_stats` and `--csv-full-history`. My tests are running correctly, but I don't see the .cvs reports in my working directory. Are there other parameters needed to create the reports? Where and when would you expect to see them?

I also have

```
stats.CSV_STATS_INTERVAL_SEC = 5
stats.CSV_STATS_FLUSH_INTERVAL_SEC = 60
```

in my locust file. I'm not totally clear from the documentation what these are doing (https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/retrieving-stats.html)

Comment: Dont set those values if you dont need to, especially avoid the second one.  

No other parameters should be needed.

Answer (score 0):

No other parameters are required. CSV reports are expected in the working directory where you kick the test. Usually, it's a project's root directory or a directory where the specific test is placed. Searching tools like "Everything" for Windows help to find files fast.